# How can I show 404 error page instead of routing error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In my Ruby on Rails application I want to show 404 error page instead of routing error when the given route does not matches or exists in my application. Can anybody help me to make it possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is already the default behavior in production. In development environment routing errors are displayed to let the developer notice them and fix them.

If you want to try it, start the server in production mode and check it.

```
$ script/rails s -e production
```

Answer (score 19):

If you cannot easily run production mode locally, set the `consider_all_requests_local` to false in your `config/environments/development.rb` file.

Answer (score 10):

in `ApplicationController`

```
 rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :rescue404
 rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, :with => :rescue404

  def rescue404
    #your custom method for errors, you can render anything you want there
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

This return 404 page

In ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

      rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound,    with: :route_not_found
      rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError,  with: :route_not_found
      rescue_from ActionController::UnknownFormat, with: :route_not_found


    def route_not_found
        render file: Rails.public_path.join('404.html'), status: :not_found, layout: false
      end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could catch exception that is thrown when a route is not found and then render a custom page. Let me know if you need help with the code. There might be many other ways to do this but this definitely works.